# Android: IntelliJ IDEA 10 - Where is the Android GUI designer?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, intellij-idea

Am I am missing something, I have the IDEA 10 installed and created an Android module. I see my main.xml in layout but it just shows me the XML. Is it not possible to design a layout using the GUI?

Eclipse has this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you desire an up to date GUI editor, unfortunately you are stuck with Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, this is no longer the case. IntelliJ IDEA 12 introduces a GUI editor. You can get the latest released development build at [this site](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP).

Answer (score 9):

### Update

IntelliJ IDEA 11 (Ultimate- *and* Community Edition) has a GUI preview.

[image]

-- http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html

### Update II

And version 12 (both the Ultimate- and Community editions) have an Android GUI designer: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/android-ui-designer-coming-in-intellij-idea-12/

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only a preview. However, the new one (version 12) is supposed to have a GUI for editing as well :)

Comment: @Betaminos, yes, you are correct. I edited my answer to include this (now that version 12 is officially released). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet available at idea 10. But Android Layout Preview will come soon to IntelliJ Idea 11 http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP#IDEA11EAP-ReleaseNotes, so please wait for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Fully-functional [UI designer for Android](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/android-ui-designer-coming-in-intellij-idea-12/) has been just announced by IntelliJ IDEA team and should appear in next version (12). The Early Access for it is about to open.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.

I've never found it an issue though as coding the layouts by hand gives a much higher level of control and understanding.

If you need a tool to use with IntelliJ IDEA, try DroidDraw
http://www.droiddraw.org/

Comment: Just be warned that DroidDraw is extremely outdated. And defaults to a deprecated layout.

Comment: @OllieC -  Are you saying that the EAP version 11 of intelliJ doesn't have a designer?

Comment: @Buzzer The Ultimate version of IntelliJ v11 certainly has the layout design preview, I don't know about the EAP.

Comment: so in other words intellij is useless as a free android ide i thought jetbrains was better than this i have always been impressed with their products until now waste of time